# AJAX in jQuery with blank "url"

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

There is a site, which passes me a parameter `token`, only if I call the base url of the site. For example, only when I call `http://www.site.com` it converts it to `http://www.site.com?token=979797979`. because of this, `url-pattern` line in my `web.xml` document looks like:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

I have servlet which processes this call, but when I am trying to call a servlet from Jquery's `$.ajax` it doesn't work, because the URL has empty string but it needs to have the empty string because the call to the site is to the home URL.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "",
    success: function(data1){ alert(data1) }
}
```

Maybe I don't understand something. Can anyone help?

Comment: The ajax has to hit an action somewhere, even if it was http://www.sitehome/

Comment: it will not work using empty url

Answer (score 0):

Try the URL "/".

jQuery should then perform a GET request on the root URL of your site – in your case "http://www.site.com".